# HTML position absolute for a table

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is inside a div. The div has a `class="bar"` and it is on the top of the screen. It has

```
top:0px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
```

The table inside this one, has 2 cells with a css `hover` that changes the color when you go over them with the mouse.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9ep6/)

Here you can see that when you go over `C / C++` the grey background doesn't stay "inside" the div. I set the table to `top:0px; left:0px; right:0px;` but it is not fixed.

[image]

I want the grey rectangle to be inside the black div. What could I do?

Comment: The height which you have given to the td #bgrect seems to be a problem...

Comment: I know but I don't know what to do :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute positioning on the `table` isn't actually needed. You can remove that and then collapse the borders of your table using [`border-collapse: collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse):

```css
#ontop {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:10; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G9ep6/3/).

Answer (score 2):

This css line will help you:

```
#bgrect { padding: 0; }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it leaves a black line at the top where the `table`'s border hasn't been collapsed.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly The table doesn't have a border. It's the cellspacing that causes the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the border-spacing on the table to 0.

```css
#ontop {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px; 
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;   
    border-spacing:0;
}
```

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/G9ep6/4/).

(And while I agree that the absolute poisitioning is not needed in this example, I'm sure you have your reasons. You don't need the z-index though...)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have duplicate `ID` in one document!
Change `#bgrect` to `.bgrect`

```
<td width="50%" class="bgrect">
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/iboWakE/1/edit)

**CSS:**

```
.bar{
    /* NO BACKGROUND ! */
    width:100%;
    height:28px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font: 67.5%'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Trebuchet Unicode MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#D8D8D8;
}
#ontop {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    border-collapse:collapse;  /* collapse borders */
}
.bgrect{
    background-color: #0C0C0C; /* initial bg */
}
.bgrect:hover {
    background-color: #2E2E2E; /*   hover bg */
    cursor:pointer;
}
```